# MYSQL IN statement returning wrong data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use the MYSQL statement IN to select only the data I need from my table. For example: I have a field that save categories by ID separated by comma (7,1,10,25,20). If I use this code:

```
SELECT * FROM cancelamento WHERE ( motivos_int_id IN ( 7 ) )
```

I get only the rows that start with the number 7. If the data from that row is 8,7,14, for example, it doesn't return any data. Even if I change the code to:

```
SELECT * FROM cancelamento WHERE ( motivos_int_id IN ( 7,8 ) )
```

Am I doing something wrong? I need to fetch all the data that has the number 7, for example, regardless of the order of the number 7.

Comment: 1. Normalize your data

Comment: @Strawberry Although I agree with you, that's not always possible. Sometimes there's just that Genius DataBase Admin™ who don't need no stinking join...

Comment: Yeah, but it's their funeral. Count me out!

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() worked for me... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
    SELECT * FROM cancelamento WHERE find_in_set(7 , motivos_int_id)
```

a little [example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33941/1)

Comment: It worked: SELECT * FROM cancelamento WHERE FIND_IN_SET(8, motivos_int_id) AND FIND_IN_SET(7, motivos_int_id);

Comment: I think this has the same caveat as using `LIKE`, that is, it won't use indexes.

Comment: @Foreba yes if you want add 8 then use AND ... and you will get what you want 7 and 8 . ok well it worked for you , good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First print your motivos_int_id  separate , 
check your id'structure it could be like this one (12,3,4,)
in last there is comma appended , so if this scenerio happend use rtrim() function in php 
and trim your right side comma  and your query is correct .

> select * from tbl_name where id IN(1,2,3)